# What is the name of the glyoxal radical after removing two hydrogen atoms?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, radicals

What is the name of the radical that results from removing two hydrogen atoms from glyoxal ($\ce{CHO-CHO}$)? It has a roughly this structure: $$\ce{O=C^.-C^.=O}$$

It is an important intermediate in heterogeneous electrocatalysis (for instance, [J. Phys. Chem. Lett. 2015, 6, 11, 2032-2037](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jpclett.5b00722)). For simplicity, in most articles it is called "carbon monoxide dimer". However, it should have a systematic name like other crucial intermediates like $\ce{-CHO}$ (formyl) or $\ce{-OCH3}$ (methoxy).

Please note that the answer is probably not ethenedione, which is the hypotetic dimer of carbon monoxide in gas phase.

Comment: It *is* ethenedione even if it's in excited state.

Answer (score 5):

The relevant rule for the systematic names of polyradicals in the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-01048)* reads as follows.

> **P-71.2.3** Multiple radical centers (Polyradicals)
> Polyradicals containing two or more radicals centers, formally derived by the removal of two or more hydrogen atoms from each of two or more different skeletal atoms of a parent hydride, are named by adding to the name of the parent hydride combinations of the suffix ‘yl’ for a monovalent radical center, ‘ylidene’ for a divalent radical center, and ‘ylidyne’ for a trivalent radical center, together with the appropriate numerical prefixes indicating the number of each kind of radical center. The final letter ‘e’ of the name of the parent hydride, if present, is elided when followed by ‘y’. All substituents, including characteristic groups, when present, are cited as prefixes. Preferred IUPAC names result from the application of this rule.

Thus, the name of the parent structure is ethane-1,2-diyl.

The characteristic aldehyde groups of the original glyoxal (preferred IUPAC name: oxaldehyde; systematic IUPAC name: ethanedial) can no longer be expressed using the suffix ‘al’. They have to be cited as prefixes now. Therefore, the complete name of the compound that is given in the question is **1,2-dioxoethane-1,2-diyl.**